# I have lost my Phone - Please help

Tags: lost-phone

I lost my phone somewhere and I know it is not in my house; it is ethier in my car or at the place where I got out of the car (which is by my school).

I do not know if my phone is dead by now and if not, then it is on silent mode. My question is:

**How can I find where my phone is?**

I got no apps and I tried the Google android device manager and it is saying no location found.

So, how do I find out where it is? I searched EVERYWHERE in the car. I need to know as soon as possible, and if there is no way you can help me, then is there anyway I can get my photos and videos etc from my LOST phone and transfer it to my NEW phone?

Answer (score -2):

There is a solution: Since Device Manager (follow the link https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager? ) does not seem to help you and since you do not have another security application for tracking your device, I am sad to having your told that your mobile phone is lost.

This means that your old phone has not been turned on since it was lost. Another option was that it had a reset after that was "lost", which means it was stolen.

I hope someone else have a good idea to help you, bui it seems you cannnot do anything to recover it unless you physically find it.

Comment: You have to acrivate this first on your phone to make it work so no this isn't helpfull right now.